# Routes are declared in routes.yaml but symfony don't found them. Even when i try using annotations

Tags: php, symfony, routes, controller, symfony6

Ihave a symfony app that ignore the roytes i can declare.
For exemple, i have this lines of code in *routes.yaml* :

```yaml
app_titi
    path: /titi
    methods: ['GET']
    defaults:
        _controller: 'App\Controller\TitiController::index'
```

I do a **cache:clear** and when i try to watch the result in my browser, no route found.

The controller exists and have the right name.

My context is Symfony 6.2, PHP 8.1, runing in Docker containers.

I tryed to create a new controller, i declared it in *routes.yaml*, same results.

I tryed to create a controller but this time using annotations, same results.

When i ask the command **router:debug**, symfony console returns an empty results.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Maybe Symfony is looking at routes defined only in controllers ! Try to add a route in your controller and run `router:debug` again

Comment: I tryed, but it does not work and nothing in **router:debug** :(

Comment: Nothing at all in `router:debug`?  Not even the _wdt route or the profilier routes?  Maybe something happened when you created your application.  Try creating a new 6.2 application, use `make:controller` to add one controller and see what `router:debug` shows.  You are also missing a `:` after `app_titi` but I am assuming that was a copy/paste issue.

Comment: I did, i created a new controller using the symfony console, but still nothing when i tip debug:router.
Yes, the yaml mistake come from the copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

For a better answer please provide your controller path and code example.

In Symfony 6.2, by default, you do not have to change routes.yaml since all route declared in controller are auto detected if you keep this inside routes.yaml.
Here is my routes.yaml for example :

```
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

kernel:
    resource: ../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

Then inside the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{

    // This not annotation but php attribute, i advise you to use it instead
    #[Route('/', name: "home")]
    public function home(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('website/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Read this to understand why symfony now use php attribute :

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-php-8-attributes

Answer (score 0):

@ThomasL

Hi, here is my routes.yaml :

```yaml
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

app_titi:
    path: /titi
    methods: ['GET']
    defaults:
        _controller: 'App\Controller\TitiController::index'
```

Others routes are now declared in attributes.

This is my Titi controller :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class TitiController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/titi', name: 'app_titi')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('titi/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'TitiController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In general you should add this sort of information to your original question.  It is quite a mystery why `debug:router` shows nothing at all and no errors.  Are you using Docker or something like that?  And you are running `debug:router` and not `router:debug`?  The latter will generate a command not defined error which is definitely not the same as not having any routes.